# I need a timer that after 30 seconds if answer wasnt given quit() the programm

Tags: python, timer

i am very new to python and i wanted to programm a little code of meme copy of who wants to become a millionaire, and i want a timer that will start, and then at 30 seconds if no answer given will quit the programm. I dont know how to do it and i need help

So, i tried multiple guides and other questions with the same title answers, but it didnt work.
here is the code (dont look and talk about russian language please)

```
import time
import pygame
from tkinter import ttk
from playsound import playsound
import winsound
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('bgsong.mp3'))
print('Я устроил ВИКТОРИНУ людей нуждающихся в деньгах!И победитель сегодняшеного шоу получит 100,000$!!!!')
time.sleep(6)
print('Также сегодня я хочу порекомендовать свою шоколадку ФИСТБЛСТ!!!')
time.sleep(2)
print('кароч викторина поехали')
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('intrques.mp3'))
time.sleep(3)
print('сколько будет 9+10?')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('ответ а-19')
time.sleep(1)
print('ответ b-21')
time.sleep(3)
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('ques.mp3'))
time.sleep(1)
print('на ответ дается 30 секунд') #'You got 30 seconds to answer'
#Тут нужен Таймер/I need timer here
a=int(input())
if a<=19:
    pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('lost.mp3'))
    time.sleep(2)
    print('неправильно, ты проиграл, нужно было взять ответ того ребенка из того самого мема')
    time.sleep(2)
    exit() #wrong answer
elif a>=21:
    print('Проверка верного ответа') #correct answer
    #доделай/ill make other part in future
```

Comment: See the pytimedinput module [link](https://pypi.org/project/pytimedinput/) which provides an input function with a time limit.

Answer (score 0):

I show you two ways in which the input could be controlled according to time.

## 1. Using the native [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library

This library provides a way to create and manage threads, allowing concurrent execution of multiple tasks within a single process.

In this approach, we create a new [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) (which is a thread subclass) whose sole purpose is to wait `countdown-time` seconds to do nothing (`lambda: None`). We are interested in seeing if the process is still alive after collecting data with `input()`.

After the `timer` definitions, goes the `input()` we want to limit by time.

Before continuing with the rest of the code, we check if the timer thread is still running with the `is_alive()` function. If it is still running, it means that the user has entered the data within the time limit, and therefore we stop the `timer` process since the time has not expired. Otherwise, we exit the program since the time has expired.

```py
import threading, sys

countdown_seconds = 30.0
timer = threading.Timer(countdown_seconds, lambda: None)


user_input = input("Please provide your answer: ") 


if timer.is_alive():
    timer.cancel()
else:
    sys.exit("Time expired :(")

print("You entered:", user_input)
```

> Please note that closing the programme without warning may lead to
> user confusion and should be avoided whenever possible. If you want to
> continue with this behaviour, you should use `exit()` function of
> [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) built-in library.
> [This
> post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/)
> talks about the differences between `exit()`, `quit()`, `sys.quit()`
> and `os._exit()`.

## 2. Using [`pytimedinput`](https://pypi.org/project/pytimedinput/)

As [user19077881](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19077881/user19077881) suggests you can simply use `pytimedinput` library. From the library itself:

```py
from pytimedinput import timedInput

userText, timedOut = timedInput("Please, do enter something: ")
if(timedOut):
    print("Timed out when waiting for input.")
    print(f"User-input so far: '{userText}'")
else:
    print(f"User-input: '{userText}'")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering my question, ill try those methods and learn it

Answer (score 0):

@juan-ca there is a mistake in your first proposition:

- you create a timer in a thread,
- then you call input() in main.

Which means the line 'if timer.is_alive():' will not be reached until the input receives data. Which is what @alexwens want to avoid!